# Using BufferedWriter.flush() in Linux sends carriage return

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java console GUI that should run in Windows and Linux. The characters typed into the console window should go to the process as soon as they are typed. I am using the write() function (with length 1) followed by a flush(). Without the flush it doesn't go to process until I press `<Enter>`. The process is echoing back characters, so I should see them in console. Everything works fine in Windows, but in Linux, apparently it sends a `<CR>` for each flush(). Because the first thing that the process does is getting a password, it gets the wrong password after first character (because is submitted by `<CR>`).

If I skip the flush, it works, but the text typed is not visible in the console till the next `<Enter>`.

Could anyone help with how to avoid those `<CR>`s to be sent with the flush()?

Thanks a lot!

Code sample:

```
        BufferedWriter writer;
        ......
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
            switch(e.getID()) {
                case KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED:
                byte b;
                b = (byte)e.getKeyChar();
                try {
                    writer.write(b);
                    writer.flush();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: If you check the code, BufferedWriter.flush() is the same on linux and windows and does add any characters.  It may be that the input of the linux program behaves differently when data is flushed to it but the issue is unlikely to be on the java side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you reading the inputs by line? Could you give us the code where you do the `flush()` and what you do before it? From the way you've explained, it's as if the flush() pushing the  to the stream when the `flush()` will not push anything that is not already in the buffer. So, I'd probably check if the  got in there before you even start flushing it.

Comment: I couldn't see anything glaringly wrong with the code. a couple of pointers: Can you log the AWT events in both Windows and Linux? Or see how many times the KEY_TYPED event is fired? Also, rather than echoing the characters to the console, if possible, could you write them to a file and see if you're still seeing the <CR>s? I'm driving at: A single byte cannot hold both the key typed and the <CR>.